# DialogFragment in a fragment. How dialog's life cycle is related to fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-alertdialog, android-dialogfragment, android-lifecycle

I show a dialog in a fragment and I would like to know what problems I can face with. Do they have the same lifecycle? What if I use fragment's fields in an inner DialogFragment class?

Comment: Are you showing it as a dialog or a child fragment?

Comment: I think it depends on what fragmentmanager you're using. If you're using the fragmentmanager/support fragment manager, then its tied to the Activity, while you can also pass childfragmentmanager in which case its gonna be tied to the parent fragment

Comment: @DeeV I'm not sure what you mean. Firstly I used an activity fragment manager and faced with a very strange behavior: I ensured that a fragment field is not null, then I showed the dialog, but very rarely the dialog crashed in onCreateDialog() because that field is null. Maybe because I need to use childFragmentManager instead of activity's one

Comment: @breakline thank you for the clear answer. It would be the best one, if you posted it. Thanks again. I couldn't find such well-explained information with a quick googling